# java - vector has always the same results

Tags: java, vector

I read an .ini File and put every property into an temporary array which i put at the end into a vector - until here it works fine.

But if I want to access every array in that vector, I get ALWAYS the same results, which is impossible. I tried it with different ways, different loops and everything different, but always the same results, here is my actuall code:

```
    tmp2 = new String[2];
    for(Enumeration e=allPropertys.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
        tmp2 = (String[])e.nextElement();
        for(int i = 0; i < tmp2.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(tmp2[i]);
        }
    }
```

And here is the code where I put everything into the vector:

```
    try {
        tmp = new String[2];

        prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(new FileReader("konfig.ini"));

        Enumeration e = prop.propertyNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {

            String key = (String)e.nextElement();
            String value = prop.getProperty( key );
            tmp[0] = key + " " +  value;
            tmp[1] = value;

            System.out.println("Property: " + tmp[0] + " und Value: " + tmp[1]);
            allPropertys.add(tmp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't tell from the code you've posted.  And who thought that writing old-style Java was a good idea?

Comment: Are you sure you put different arrays in? As opposed to the same array which you were updating in-place in a loop?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'm not very much into Java, so I don't know what you mean with old-style :( sorry

Comment: Could you show us the code which populates `allPropertys`?

Comment: I tried this code with `allPropertys.add( new String[] { "Key1" , "Value1" } );allPropertys.add( new String[] { "Key2" , "Value2" } );`. This outputs both key-value pairs. So, your bug is elsewhere.

Comment: I haven't seen Enumeration used since JDK 5 came out.  Most people would prefer the new-style for loops to iterate over a collection.

Comment: All right, didn't know that, I will use a loop instead, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that when you populate your vector, you reuse the same string array for every property. This makes you vector contain 10 times (10 being the number of entries) the same array:

```
String[] property = new String[2];
for (every line in the file) {
    property[0] = ...;
    property[1] = ...;
    vector.add(property);
}
```

This should be replaced by

```
for (every line in the file) {
    String[] property = new String[2];
    property[0] = ...;
    property[1] = ...;
    vector.add(property);
}
```

Also, note in your code snippet, you create a new String array to initialize your tmp2 variable, and then replace its value by the one in the vector. The initialization is unnecessary.

Comment: It worked now - I don't really understand why, because doesn't I override the contents of the array everytime i run the loop?

Comment: You overwrite the contents of the array, but reuse the same array each time. The vector holds a pointer to your arrays. It doesn't make a copy of its contents. So if you use the same array for each line, the vector holds 10 different pointers to the same array, which contains the contents of the last line of the file.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your help, I was sitting on this for too long! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the values inside the array and putting the very-same array into the collection once and again.

You must understand how objects and arrays work. You think that adding it to a collection copies it or something (that's why you initialize the array before the loop in the reading part, I think). It only adds the reference. You always work with references.

You must create a new array for each time you want to add it. Think of an array variable (or any object variable) as a reference to an object. As an arrow to the real thing. When you add it to the vector you are adding arrows to the same structure in memory (the same two buckets).